# How to lose margin/padding in UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in my iOS application, which displays a large amount of text.

I am then paging this text by using the offset margin parameter of the `UITextView`.

My problem is that the padding of the `UITextView` is confusing my calculations as it seems to be different depending on the font size and typeface that I use.

Is it possible to remove the padding surrounding the content of the `UITextView`?

Comment: Note that this QA is almost ten years old!  With 100,000+ views, since it's one of the **stupidest problems in iOS**.  Just FTR I put in the current, 2017, reasonably simple / usual / accepted solution below as an answer.

Comment: I still get updates on this, having written a hardcoded workaround in 2009 when IOS 3.0 had just been released.  I just edited the answer to clearly state that it is years out of date and to ignore the accepted status.

Comment: Amazingly, well over ten years now (200,000 views of this QA!) and Apple *still* have not fixed the combination of plain bugs, soft bugs, and bizarre behavior in UITextView. It is really one of the weirdest things in all of mobile computing development!

Answer (score 490, accepted):

## Up-to-date for 2023

It is one of the silliest bugs in iOS.

The class given here, `UITextViewFixed` is used widely and is usually the **most reasonable solution overall**.

Here is the class:

```
@IBDesignable class UITextViewFixed: UITextView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }
    func setup() {
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    }
}
```

Don't forget to turn off scrollEnabled in the Inspector!

1. The solution works properly in storyboard
2. The solution works properly at runtime

You're done. In general, **that should be all you need in most cases**.

Even if you are changing the height of the text view **on the fly**, `UITextViewFixed` usually does all you need.

(A common example of changing the height on the fly, is changing it as the user types.)

Here is the broken UITextView from Apple...

[image: Screenshot of Interface Builder with UITextView]

Here is `UITextViewFixed`:

[image: Screenshot of Interface Builder with UITextViewFixed]

Note that of course you must...

## ...turn off scrollEnabled in the Inspector!

(Turning on scrollEnabled means "make this view expand as much as possible vertically by expanding the bottom margin as much as possible.")

---

## Some further issues

(1) In very unusual cases when dynamically changing heights, Apple does a bizarre thing: ***they add extra space at the bottom***.

No, really! This would have to be one of the most infuriating things in iOS.

If you encounter the problem, here is a "quick fix" which ***usually*** helps:

```
...
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0

        // this is not ideal, but sometimes this "quick fix"
        // will solve the "extra space at the bottom" insanity:
        var b = bounds
        let h = sizeThatFits(CGSize(
           width: bounds.size.width,
           height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
       ).height
       b.size.height = h
       bounds = b
 ...
```

(2) In rare cases, to fix yet another subtle mess-up by Apple, you have to add:

```
override func setContentOffset(_ contentOffset: CGPoint, animated: Bool) {
    super.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false) // sic
}
```

(3) Arguably, we *should* be adding:

```
contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

just after `.lineFragmentPadding = 0` in `UITextViewFixed`.

However believe or not that ***just doesn't work*** in current iOS! (Checked 2023.)  It may be necessary to add that line in the future.

The fact that `UITextView` is broken in iOS is one of the weirdest things in all of mobile computing.  Ten year anniversary of this question and it's still not fixed!

Finally, here's a somewhat similar tip for Text**Field**: *[Set the maximum character length of a UITextField in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363216/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield-in-swift/43099816#43099816)*

## Completely random tip: how to add the "..." on the end

Often you are using a UITextView "like a UILabel".  So you want it to truncate text using an ellipsis, "..."

If so, add:

```
 textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

## Handy tip if you want *zero* height, when, there's *no* text at all

Often you use a text view to only display text. So, you use lines "0" to mean the text view will automatically change height depending on how many lines of text.

That's great. But **if there is no text at all**, then unfortunately you get the same height **as if there is one line of text**!!!! The text view never "goes away".

[image]

If you want it to "go away", just add this

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    var i = super.intrinsicContentSize
    print("for \(text) size will be \(i)")
    if text == "" { i.height = 1.0 }
    print("   but we changed it to \(i)")
    return i
}
```

[image]

(I made it '1' height, so it's clear what's going on in that demo, '0' is fine.)

## What about UILabel?

When just displaying text, UILabel has many advantages over UITextView. UILabel does not suffer from the problems described on this Q&A page.

Indeed the reason we all usually "give up" and just use UITextView is that UILabel is difficult to work with. In particular it is ridiculously difficult to just add **padding**, correctly, to UILabel.

In fact here is a full discussion on how to "finally" correctly add padding to UILabel: *[Adding space/padding to a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459746/adding-space-padding-to-a-uilabel/58876988#58876988)*.  In some cases if you are doing a difficult layout with dynamic height cells, it is sometimes better to do it the hard way with UILabel.

Comment: Why do you say it's necessary to turn off scrollEnabled in the inspector? When I do that I seem to get even less space in the my text view.

Comment: The height of the frame of the scroll view is unrelated to the content size. The question posed by OP makes no mention of height. Simply trying to understand your response.

Comment: I've posted an updated answer to @Fattie's answer which helped me to really get rid of all insets using the special trick of enabling/disabling `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. 
With this answer alone I was not able to remove all the margins (some strange bottom margin resisted to go away) in a view hierarchy using auto layout.
It also deals with calculation of view sizes using `systemLayoutSizeFitting`, which previously returned an invalid size due to the buggy `UITextView`

Comment: I'm on Xcode 10.1 and using Swift 4 and i found Fattie's solution works for me if i kept scrollEnabled turned on and i used the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints trick mentioned in @Fab1n answer/comment. With scrollEnabled turned off , it still runs and looks okay in the simulator, but it doesn't look right in the storyboard

Comment: I had textviews in table, the ones that had single line of text didn't calculate its height correctly (autolayout). To fix it I had to override didMoveToSuperview and call setup there also.

Comment: @Fattie , Constraints are fine, there is always 1 or 2 extra row at the bottom. It works OK if I use regular UITextView. I just tested it with simple test project and same problem occurs. I've put UITextViewFixed in table cell with top/bottom/leading/trailing constraints. I've put test project on dropbox if you want to test it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7ci6j0m1apc3l5/TestApp.zip?dl=0

Comment: I used this in my app and it causes a recursive call between layoutSubviews and setup causing a stack overflow error! Something is wrong here

Comment: I had the extra spacing at the bottom issue when using a UITableViewCell. I found that doing the sizeThatFits part in layoutSubview froze my app (infinite loop?) if I attempted to edit the text view. Instead, I did what El Horrible suggested and that works fine.

Comment: Guys take care using didMoveToSuperview - although it can seemingly work in simple cases, if you don't something in layout, it will, of course, never size properly as the layout changes!  Regarding the other comment, in iOS programming it's easy to accidentally have an infinite loop in your custom classes, I certainly often do it!, it is unrelated to anything here.)

Comment: Great collation of info. Unfortunately neither of the two fixes for that extra space at the bottom works for me. When UITextView contains 1 line, there's no extra bottom padding. When it contains 2 or 3 lines, there is. Using `UITextViewFixed` and applying all fixes you've suggested, testing both with & without the two optional ones.

Comment: When I try your first fix for extra bottom space, the height remains the same, but text is incorrectly offset in the Y axis, as though top inset padding is unzeroed. The only working solution I've found for a tight-fitting UITextView that has dynamic self-sizing is to override `intrinsicContentSize` and fudge-adjust the calculated height by subtracting `0.4 * font.lineHeight`, in the case where there's more than one visible line.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, #1 in "Some further issues" may lead to recursive call. Instead of trying to fix that extra space at the bottom in the layoutSubviews(), we should note that this behaviour is not at all unexpected. It happens because the layout engine first calculates the height before layoutSubviews() is fired. Therefore it takes into account the original top and bottom insets and sticks with the hight afterwards. With that in mind the solution should be to make the same adjust

Comment: #1 in "Some further issues" solution may lead to recursive call. That extra space at the bottom is not at all unexpected though. It happens because the layout engine first calculates the height before `layoutSubviews()` is fired. Therefore it takes into account the original top and bottom insets and sticks with the height afterwards. Based on that, my solution was to make the same text container adjustments in `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` as proposed in `layoutSubviews()`. WIth that you don't have to manipulate the bounds in `layoutSubviews()`.

Comment: @Dmitry for sure, anytime at all you use layoutSubviews you risk making a mistake and ending up in a loop and crash!  It's a good idea to use `required init?(coder` but that would also take some thought about the layout cycle and, perhaps, you'd have to be careful if code v. storyboard bringup?

Answer (score 846):

For iOS 7.0, I've found that the contentInset trick no longer works. This is the code I used to get rid of the margin/padding in iOS 7.

This brings the left edge of the text to the left edge of the container:

```
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
```

This causes the top of the text to align with the top of the container:

```
textView.textContainerInset = .zero
```

Both lines are needed to completely remove the margin/padding.

Comment: This is working for me for two lines, but by the time I get to 5 lines, the text is getting cut off.

Comment: This worked great for me, with multiple lines (10+), and using an embedded font. Thanks user1687195.

Comment: Note that the second line can also be written as:

`self.descriptionTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`

Comment: Didn't manage to remove the top/bottom padding with this solution

Comment: For vertical align the content of text view with text label, the first line only works for me in iOS 7.

Comment: Setting `lineFragmentPadding` to 0 is the magic I was looking for. I have no idea why Apple makes it so hard to line up UITextView content with other controls.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Scrolling horizontally doesn't happen with this solution.

Comment: Works nice in iOS7 and above. :-]

Comment: I like this solution the best. Setting the insets to hard coded values (for example: UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)) is sketchy at best since the defaults could change with every version of the OS.

Comment: `lineFragmentPadding` is not intended to modify margins. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextContainer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTextContainer/lineFragmentPadding) _Line fragment padding is not designed to express text margins. Instead, you should use insets on your text view, adjust the paragraph margin attributes, or change the position of the text view within its superview._

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. I'm baffled by Apple's statement that this was not designed to express text margins. I suppose you could just set the left inset to -lineFragmentPadding instead of changing this, which makes it a bit cleaner. In any case, this solution is FAR cleaner than a bunch of hardcoded insets.

Comment: @SergeyGrischyov - regarding the insane **"bottom space problem"**, I give the only solution in my answer below.  Apple madness.

Comment: While the *particular* point given in this answer is totally correct, it, very simply, does not "remove the stupid padding from a text view" as asked in the question.  Since this QA is very old, I typed in the correct current answer below - look for the yellow screenshots!  :)  Hope it helps someone.

Comment: You probably also want to disable scrolling

Answer (score 259):

**This workaround was written in 2009 when iOS 3.0 was released. It no longer applies.**

I ran into the exact same problem, and in the end I had to wind up using

```
nameField.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4, -8, 0, 0);
```

where nameField is a `UITextView`.  The font I happened to be using was Helvetica 16 point. It’s only a custom solution for the particular field size I was drawing.  This makes the left offset flush with the left side, and the top offset where I want it for the box it’s drawn in.

In addition, this only seems to apply to `UITextViews` where you are using the default aligment, i.e.,

```
nameField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

Align to the right for example and the `UIEdgeInsetsMake` seems to have no impact on the right edge at all.

At very least, using the .contentInset property allows you to place your fields with the "correct" positions, and accommodate the deviations without offsetting your `UITextViews`.

Comment: I'm resorting to making the TextView's frame extend farther to the right.  At about 16.0 additional points the wrapping behavior of my textview and my label match up.  Not crazy about this approach.

Comment: 16.0f makes sense, so I'm not too worried. I believe the UITextView underestimates its own size by 16.0f as a direct result of insetting by 8.0f on the left and right edges.

Comment: Yes it does work in iOS 7. Make sure the UIEdgeInset is set to the right values. It might be different than UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4,-8,0,0).

Comment: In IOS 7 I found UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,-4,0,-4) worked the best.

Comment: Yes, those are example numbers. I stated "Its only a custom solution for the particular field size I was drawing".  Mainly I was trying to illustrate that you have to play with the numbers for your unique layout situation.

Comment: UITextAlignmentLeft is deprecated in iOS 7. Use NSTextAlignmentLeft.

Comment: UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8,-4,0,0) works best for me. *shrug*

Comment: UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8,-4,-8,-4) gets rid of the padding on all four sides. iOS 8.

Comment: I don't get why people upvote an answer that utilizes hard-coded values. It is VERY likely to break in future versions of iOS and is just a plain bad idea.

Comment: As can be seen from the comments the specific values for the `contentInset` depends on font, UIKit and potentially other factors. The correct answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/18987810/1555903

Comment: This is a hacky solution, set the 'textContainer' lineFragmentPadding to 0 instead.

Answer (score 87):

Building off some of the good answers already given, here is a purely Storyboard / Interface Builder-based solution that works in iOS 7.0+

Set the UITextView's **User Defined Runtime Attributes** for the following keys:

```
textContainer.lineFragmentPadding
textContainerInset
```

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: This is clearly the best answer, especially if you need a XIB-only solution

Comment: Copy/paste: textContainer.lineFragmentPadding | textContainerInset

Comment: This is what makes a beautiful answer - easy and works well, even after 3 years :)

Comment: The people praising this answer .)) I'm sorry but this is such a terrible and lazy way of setting properties. If ever the properties change, you're gonne get runtime crashes instead of compile-time. User Defined Runtime Attributes were a terrible hack, when Apple was still trying pushing storyoboards and XIBs. Please never do this, drop all storyboards and work in code.

Answer (score 47):

On iOS 5 `UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8,-8,-8,-8);` seems to work great.

Answer (score 44):

I would definitely avoid any answers involving hard-coded values, as the actual margins may change with user font-size settings, etc.

Here is [user1687195's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746670/how-to-lose-margin-padding-in-uitextview/18987810#18987810), written without modifying the `textContainer.lineFragmentPadding` (because the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextContainer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTextContainer/lineFragmentPadding) state this is not the intended usage).

**This works great for iOS 7 and later.**

```
self.textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
                                      0,
                                      -self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding,
                                      0,
                                      -self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding);
```

This is effectively the same outcome, just a bit cleaner in that it doesn't misuse the lineFragmentPadding property.

Comment: I tried another solution based on this answer and it works great. The solutions is: `self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;`

Comment: @BakytAbdrasulov please read my answer. While your solution works, it is not in accordance with the docs (see the link in my answer). `lineFragmentPadding` isn't meant to control the margins. That's why you're supposed to use `textContainerInset`.

Answer (score 25):

Storyboard or Interface Builder solution using **user-defined runtime attributes**:

Screenshots are of iOS 7.1 & iOS 6.1 with `contentInset = {{-10, -5}, {0, 0}}`.

[image: user-defined runtime attributes]

[image: Output]

Comment: Worked for me in iOS 7.

Comment: Up just for user defined runtime attributes - awesome!

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `textContainerInset` property of `UITextView`:

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

(top, left, bottom, right)

Comment: I wonder why this is not assigned as the best answer here. The textContainerInset really satisfied my needs.

Comment: Updating the bottom value on the `textContainerInset` property isn't working for me when I want to change it to a new value—see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422578/uitextview-textcontainerinset-not-respecting-bottom-inset-value.

Comment: @MaggiePhillips It's not the best answer because hardcoded values can't possibly be the right way to do this, and are guaranteed to fail in some cases. You need to take lineFragmentPadding into account.

Answer (score 17):

All these answers address the title question, but I wanted to propose some solutions for the problems presented in the body of the OP's question.

#### Size of Text Content

A quick way to calculate the size of the text inside the `UITextView` is to use the `NSLayoutManager`:

```
UITextView *textView;
CGSize textSize = [textView usedRectForTextContainer:textView.textContainer].size;
```

This gives the total scrollable content, which may be bigger than the `UITextView`'s frame. I found this to be much more accurate than `textView.contentSize` since it actually calculates how much space the text takes up. For example, given an empty `UITextView`:

```
textView.frame.size = (width=246, height=50)
textSize = (width=10, height=16.701999999999998)
textView.contentSize = (width=246, height=33)
textView.textContainerInset = (top=8, left=0, bottom=8, right=0)
```

#### Line Height

`UIFont` has a property that quickly allows you to get the line height for the given font. So you can quickly find the line height of the text in your `UITextView` with:

```
UITextView *textView;
CGFloat lineHeight = textView.font.lineHeight;
```

#### Calculating Visible Text Size

Determining the amount of text that is actually visible is important for handling a "paging" effect. `UITextView` has a property called `textContainerInset` which actually is a margin between the actual `UITextView.frame` and the text itself. To calculate the real height of the visible frame you can perform the following calculations:

```
UITextView *textView;
CGFloat textViewHeight = textView.frame.size.height;
UIEdgeInsets textInsets = textView.textContainerInset;
CGFloat textHeight = textViewHeight - textInsets.top - textInsets.bottom;
```

#### Determining Paging Size

Lastly, now that you have the visible text size and the content, you can quickly determine what your offsets should be by subtracting the `textHeight` from the `textSize`:

```
// where n is the page number you want
CGFloat pageOffsetY = textSize - textHeight * (n - 1);
textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(textView.contentOffset.x, pageOffsetY);

// examples
CGFloat page1Offset = 0;
CGFloat page2Offset = textSize - textHeight
CGFloat page3Offset = textSize - textHeight * 2
```

Using all of these methods, I didn't touch my insets and I was able to go to the caret or wherever in the text that I want.

Answer (score 14):

Here is an updated version of [Fattie's very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746670/how-to-lose-margin-padding-in-uitextview/42333832#42333832).
It added two important lines that helped me get the layout working on iOS 10 and 11 (and probably on lower ones, too):

```swift
@IBDesignable class UITextViewFixed: UITextView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }
    func setup() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

**The important lines are the two `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = <true/false>` statements!**

This surprisingly **removes all margins** in all my circumstances!

While the `textView` is not the first responder, it could happen that there is some strange bottom margin that could not be solved using the `sizeThatFits` method that is mentioned in the accepted answer.

When tapping into the textView, suddenly the strange bottom margin disappeared and everything looked like it should, but only as soon as the textView has got `firstResponder`.

So I read [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186908/can-i-use-setframe-and-autolayout-on-the-same-view) that enabling and disabling `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` does help when setting the frame/bounds manually in between the calls.

Fortunately this not only works with frame setting, but with the two lines of `setup()` sandwiched between the two `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` calls!

This, for example, is **very helpful** when calculating the frame of a view **using `systemLayoutSizeFitting` on a `UIView`**. It gives back the correct size (which previously it didn't)!

As in the original answer mentioned:

*Don't forget to turn off scrollEnabled in the Inspector! That solution does work properly in storyboard, as well as at runtime.*

**That's it, and now you're *really* done!**

Answer (score 12):

For iOS 10, the following line works for the top and bottom padding removing.

```
captionTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Xcode 8.2.1. still the same issue as mentioned in this answer. My solution was to edit the values as UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -4.0, bottom: 0, right: -4.0).

Comment: `UIEdgeInset.zero` works using XCode 8.3 and iOS 10.3 Simulator

Answer (score 12):

Latest Swift:

```
self.textView.textContainerInset = .init(top: -2, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
```

Comment: Great answer. This answer removes the additional Top inset.
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero doesn't remove 2 pixels from top inset.

Answer (score 6):

**For Swift 4, Xcode 9**

Use the following function. It can change the margin/padding of the text in UITextView:

```
public func UIEdgeInsetsMake(_ top: CGFloat, _ left: CGFloat, _ bottom: CGFloat, _ right: CGFloat) -> UIEdgeInsets
```

So in this case it is:

```
 self.textView?.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

**For [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/)**

If you are making your own TextView using `UIViewRepresentable` and want to control the padding, in your `makeUIView` function, simply do:

`uiTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 18, bottom: 0, right: 18)`

or whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

Doing the inset solution I still had padding on the right side and the bottom. Also text alignment was causing issues. The only sure-fire way I found was to put the text view inside another view that is clipped to bounds.

Comment: What is the *"inset solution"*? Can you elaborate and/or add a reference? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5507746/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easy little extension that will remove Apple's default margin from every text view in your app.

Note: Interface Builder will still show the old margin, but your app will work as expected.

```
extension UITextView {

   open override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib();
      removeMargins();
   }

   /** Removes the Apple textview margins. */
   public func removeMargins() {
      self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
         0, -textContainer.lineFragmentPadding,
         0, -textContainer.lineFragmentPadding);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me (iOS 11 & Xcode 9.4.1) what worked magically was setting up textView.font property to `UIFont.preferred(forTextStyle:UIFontTextStyle)` style and also the first answer as [mentioned by Fattie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746670/how-to-lose-margin-padding-in-uitextview/42333832#42333832). But the Fattie answer did not work till I set the textView.font property. Else UITextView keeps behaving erratically.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is looking for the latest Swift version then the below code is working fine with **Xcode 10.2** and **Swift 4.2**

```
yourTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found one more approach. Getting the view with text from UITextView's subviews and setting it up in the layoutSubview method of a subclass:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    const int textViewIndex = 1;
    UIView *textView = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:textViewIndex];
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(
                                 kStatusViewContentOffset,
                                 0.0f,
                                 self.bounds.size.width - (2.0f * kStatusViewContentOffset),
                                 self.bounds.size.height - kStatusViewContentOffset);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The textView scrolling also affect the position of the text and make it look like not vertically centered. I managed to center the text in the view by disabling the scrolling and setting the top inset to 0:

```
    textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, textView.textContainerInset.left, textView.textContainerInset.bottom, textView.textContainerInset.right);
```

For some reason I haven't figured it out yet, the cursor is still not centered before the typing begins, but the text centers immediately as I start typing.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to set an HTML string and avoid the bottom padding, please make sure that you are not using block tags, i.e., `div` and `p`.

In my case this was the reason. You can easily test it out by replacing occurrences of block tags with, e.g., the `span` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set inset and lineFragmentPadding on didMoveToSuperView

```
@IBDesignable class UITextViewFixed: UITextView {
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        setup()
    }
    func setup() {
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it `textContainerInset`? Not `textContainer.Inset`?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this because of parsing HTML into UITextView, just remove the new line introduced by the closing p tag "/n". I assume that you work with **NSMutableAttributedString**:

```
if let lastCharacter = attributedString.string.last, lastCharacter == "\n" {
    attributedString.deleteCharacters(in: NSRange(location:(attributedString.length) - 1, length:1))
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
[firstNameTextField setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7033311/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).