# Determine padding and size of iOS UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

#### Project

I am attempting to replicate the native iMessage app. I have used [AcaniChat](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat/) as a foundation.

I wanted automatic *highlighting*, so I modified the code to use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`. I realize there are options such as [FancyLabel](http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/) and [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20). However, `UITextView` does this natively.

#### Problem

I am having a difficult time getting the padding/size of `UITextView` right. I updated the `contentInset` property based on suggestions in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746670/how-to-lose-margin-padding-in-uitextview).

```
msgText.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-11.0f, -8.0f, 0.0f, -8.0f);
```

I am also determining the size with the following:

```
CGSize size = [[(Message *)object text] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:kMessageFontSize]
                                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(kMessageTextWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                       lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Nonetheless, some text is still being cut off (see image below). Notably the phone number and email address (right) as well as the "that cut off?" (left)

I have verified this is not due to the `dataDetectorsTypes` property.

#### Question

I can solve this by increasing the `CGRect` of the `UITextView`. But I want to better understand the affects of margin/padding and size of the `UITextView`. I don't want to arbitrarily increase the size by `20.0f` to *make it work*.

As such, what is *the* code or combination of code that I can reliably set the size of the message bubble?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution for your problems with UITextView but ...
I had similar problems and decided to give core text a chance. You have simply more control about what is happening.
You could have your string attributed using regex statements to make links/emails/phone numbers visible and have furthermore the chance to use even other fonts.

Comment: Core Text is a technology for text layout and font processing. Have a look in the "Core Text Programming Guide".

Comment: Basis is an NSAttributedString - a string where attributes are assigned to parts of the string as font/font size/color etc. You can find several sample projects in Xcode's documentation as well as on Github (e.g. akosma / CoreTextWrapper; jonasschnelli / I7CoreTextExample).