# Change iOS TextView padding in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I created a ViewController with a TextView and inserted some text (with scroll). My problem is that by default this padding on top shows up and I want to remove it **using storyboard** and also change the padding on left and right of it. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lose margin/padding in UITextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746670/how-to-lose-margin-padding-in-uitextview)

Comment: I tried the storyboard answers, without success... Even in runtime

Comment: I don't think your issue is "padding", it might be your layout that is at wrong here now that I read your question again, so the title is misleading and you should investigate your layout by changing the background colors of the different properties (scrollcontentView, textView, self.view , etc) to visually know where things "start" and "end" in your layout before you call it out as padding. GL.

Comment: My problem was solved by unchecking "Adjust Scroll View Insets", this strange padding disappeared! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click on the viewcontroller and[image: check the image] then go to Attribute Inspector
Remove the tick on Under top bar