# How to remove the blank text container on empty UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I've already set the properties `textContainerInset` and `lineFragmentPadding` to zero as seen on this code thanks to this removing the padding and margin via this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42333832/5928180).

```
// this is inside a UITextView Subclass
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.textContainerInset = .zero
    self.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
}
```

Here's how the `UITextView` renders when it has text

[image]

Here it is with multiple lines

[image]

Here's how it renders without text

[image]

Is it possible to make the height `0` if the `UITextView`'s text is empty?

**Edit**:

1. There is no constraint being used on the `UITextView` and I'm not planning to set a height constraint as I want this `UITextView` to automatically resize depending on the **text** being set into it
2. This is a `isScrollEnabled = false` UITextView inside a UITableViewCell, which automatically resizes depending on the data fetched from the api server.

**About**:

Language: Swift 3.2

IDE: Xcode 9.2

Comment: Are you using `Constraints ` for this textview?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed no there is no height constraint for the textview.

Comment: have you got any answer ? am facing the same issue

Comment: @karthik See the selected answer down below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [uhuru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8893378/uhuru)'s answer I've formulated an answer to the code of mine that wouldn't need too much of an overhaul.

First I've setup a height constraint for the `UITextView` programatically.

```
// outside the scope
var contentTextViewConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

// inside awakeFromNib
self.contentTextViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: self.lblContent,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height,
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
    toItem: nil,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute,
    multiplier: 1,
    constant: 0)
self.contentTextViewConstraint?.isActive = false
```

Then activate/deactivate the constraint depending on the `String`

```
// inside the setup
let contentText: String = model.contentText
self.tvContent.text = contentText
self.contentTextViewConstraint?.isActive = contentText.isEmpty
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set two height constraints for the TVw. One with your desired height and the other one with 0 height and less priority.

Then on the TextView's delegate do something like:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    constraint.isActive = textView.text.count != 0
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll try implementing something like this in a different format

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
CGSize sizeThatFitsTextView = [TextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(TextView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];
TextViewHeightConstraint.constant = sizeThatFitsTextView.height;
```

Answer (score -1):

Another possible solution is to add a constraint in InterfaceBuilder for `height == 0`, set it as `isActive == false` and give it a custom identifier.

Activate/deactivate it when needed in the code using :

`textView.constraints.first { $0.identifier == "theConstrainIdentifier" }?.isActive = false // or true`

Answer (score -2):

This may be UITextView's bug. Try to follow code:

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    CGSize size = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    if ((size.width < FLT_EPSILON || size.height < FLT_EPSILON) && self.textStorage.string.length == 0) {
        return CGSizeZero;
    } else {
        return size;
    }
}
```