# Convert from SwiftUI.Font to UIFont

Tags: fonts, swiftui, uifont

I have a `UIViewRepresentable` with a `UITextView` and I want to set the font on the `UITextView` using the current `Font` from the SwiftUI environment. I just need a simple init like:

```
UIFont(_ swiftUIFont: Font)
```

But I can't find any such thing. And the `Font` type doesn't seem to have any information I can use to try to implement one. Anyone know of a way to convert between the two font representations?

Comment: unfortunately, not yet (at least, I didn't find any way), fill the radar ...

Comment: Keep in mind:  `SwiftUI.Font` is a `View`, where `UITextView.font` is a UIFont

Comment: @ninestones `SwiftUI.Font` is just a plain `Struct` conforms to
`Equatable` and 
`Hashable`, not a `View`:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font

Comment: https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNSwiftUIUtils

I've created a small library, which includes a Font -> UIFont conversion method. It supports all modifiers but the `leading()` one.

Answer (score 17):

A bit of a hack but works (doing the other direction is left as an exercise to the reader).

```swift
extension UIFont {
    class func preferredFont(from font: Font) -> UIFont {
        let uiFont: UIFont
        
        switch font {
        case .largeTitle:
            uiFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
        case .title:
            uiFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        case .title2:
            uiFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title2)
        case .title3:
            uiFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title3)
        case .headline:
            uiFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        case .subheadline:
            uiFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
        case .callout:
            uiFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .callout)
        case .caption:
            uiFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        case .caption2:
            uiFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption2)
        case .footnote:
            uiFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote)
        case .body:
            fallthrough
        default:
            uiFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        }
        
        return uiFont
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not support custom font designs (rounded, etc), custom sizes/weights or custom fonts. I suggest people create feedbacks for Apple to support retrieving a `UIFont` or `NSFont` instance from `Font` directly.

Comment: @Luke_Howard perhaps change the method name to `preferredFont(from font:Font)` to reflect that this only returns default system font.

Comment: I don't think that this answers the OP's question. There's the assumption of using the default font. What if the OP loaded a custom font?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a reformatting of Luke Howard's solution to reduce the amount of text

```
extension UIFont {
  class func preferredFont(from font: Font) -> UIFont {
      let style: UIFont.TextStyle
      switch font {
        case .largeTitle:  style = .largeTitle
        case .title:       style = .title1
        case .title2:      style = .title2
        case .title3:      style = .title3
        case .headline:    style = .headline
        case .subheadline: style = .subheadline
        case .callout:     style = .callout
        case .caption:     style = .caption1
        case .caption2:    style = .caption2
        case .footnote:    style = .footnote
        case .body: fallthrough
        default:           style = .body
     }
     return  UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: style)
   }
}
```

From Swift 5.9, you can use the switch statement to return a value and have an even less cluttered look:

```
extension UIFont {
  class func preferredFont(from font: Font) -> UIFont {
      let style: UIFont.TextStyle =
      switch font {
        case .largeTitle:   .largeTitle
        case .title:        .title1
        case .title2:       .title2
        case .title3:       .title3
        case .headline:     .headline
        case .subheadline:  .subheadline
        case .callout:      .callout
        case .caption:      .caption1
        case .caption2:     .caption2
        case .footnote:     .footnote
        default: /*.body */ .body 
      }
      return  UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: style)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Nice piece of re-factoring.

Comment: Note that this works equally well for `NSFont`.

Comment: I have added a version that works with the new syntax feature in Swift 5.9, of allowing switch to return a value

Answer (score 3):

It's a good question and although as mentioned in the other answers, you can't convert `SwiftUI.Font` directly to `UIFont`, but you can easily work around it by using Foundation's `AttributedString`. Here's how I did it for `UILabel`:

```
func updateUIView(_ label: UILabel, context: Context) {
    var container = AttributeContainer()
    container.font = context.environment.font

    let attributedString = AttributedString(text, attributes: container)
    label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(attributedString)
}
```

Comment: (A) I'm not following how this addresses the question of finding a `UIFont` that corresponds to a given `SwiftUI.Font`. (B) It sounds like you provided a workaround, but I'm not seeing the connection yet. Could you flesh out your explanation please?

Comment: Hey @DavidJ. you're right. I tried to give an answer to the question, which was about using it in a `UIViewRepresentable` with `UITextView`. You could perhaps (ab)use the AttributeContainer to convert between the two by using the `swiftUI` and `uiKit` atributes on that container: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, you have to use the params you passed to the `Font` to create `UIFont`