# How to disable highlighted text in TextField in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swiftui, textfield, highlight, one-time-password

I created an OTP field using textfield but I want to disable highlighting the text when you double tap or longpress on a TextField.

I tried adjusting the font size to 0. This seems to shrink the grey highlight but it did not hide it totally.

I can't use **textSelection(.disabled)** because I can only use Xcode 12.3 and this API seems to be available in higher Xcode versions.

I also cannot adjust the frame width of textField to 0 when editing is true because the paste functionality would be disable. Paste to text is a needed requirement.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class OTPViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var numberOfFields: Int
    
    init(numberOfFields: Int = 6) {
        self.numberOfFields = numberOfFields
    }
    
    @Published var otpField = "" {
        didSet {
            guard otpField.last?.isNumber ?? true else {
                otpField = oldValue
                return
            }
            if otpField.count == numberOfFields {
                hideKeyboard()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Published var isEditing = false
    
    func otp(digit: Int) -> String {
        guard otpField.count >= digit else {
            return ""
        }
        return String(Array(otpField)[digit - 1])
    }
    
    private func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct OTPView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = OTPViewModel()
    
    private let textBoxWidth: CGFloat = 41
    private let textBoxHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 8
    private let spaceBetweenLines: CGFloat = 16
    private let paddingOfBox: CGFloat = 1
    private var textFieldOriginalWidth: CGFloat {
        (textBoxWidth + CGFloat(18)) * CGFloat(viewModel.numberOfFields)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                HStack (spacing: spaceBetweenLines) {
                    ForEach(1 ... viewModel.numberOfFields, id: \.self) { digit in
                        otpText(
                            text: viewModel.otp(digit: digit),
                            isEditing: viewModel.isEditing,
                            beforeCursor: digit - 1 < viewModel.otpField.count,
                            afterCursor: viewModel.otpField.count < digit - 1
                        )
                    }
                } //: HSTACK
                TextField("", text: $viewModel.otpField) { isEditing in
                    viewModel.isEditing = isEditing
                }
                .font(Font.system(size: 90, design: .default))
                .offset(x: 12, y: 10)
                .frame(width: textFieldOriginalWidth, height: textBoxHeight)
                .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .background(Color.clear)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .accentColor(.clear)
                
            } //: ZSTACK
        } //: VSTACK
    }
    
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    private func otpText(
        text: String,
        isEditing: Bool,
        beforeCursor: Bool,
        afterCursor: Bool
    ) -> some View {
        return Text(text)
            .font(Font.custom("GTWalsheim-Regular", size: 34))
            .frame(width: textBoxWidth, height: textBoxHeight)
            .background(VStack{
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 65)
                ZStack {
                    Capsule()
                        .frame(width: textBoxWidth, height: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "#BCBEC0"))
                    
                    Capsule()
                        .frame(width: textBoxWidth, height: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "#367878"))
                        .offset(x: (beforeCursor ? textBoxWidth : 0) + (afterCursor ? -textBoxWidth : 0))
                        .animation(.easeInOut, value: [beforeCursor, afterCursor])
                        .opacity(isEditing ? 1 : 0)
                } //: ZSTACK
                .clipped()
            })
            .padding(paddingOfBox)
            .accentColor(.clear)
    }
}
```

Comment: you may find this SO answer of use (towards the end of the answer set). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58005434/how-do-i-allow-text-selection-on-a-text-label-in-swiftui

Comment: hi @workingdog, which answer do you mean? I saw this post but this is to allow selection. I want to disable mine.

Comment: the answer from "jbaraga", it says "....I wanted in essence to select the text without allowing editing". The second last answer, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the frame of the TextField.

```
.frame(width: textFieldOriginalWidth, height: textBoxHeight)
```

Change the width to be reactive to the `isEditing` state. If true make the width `0` otherwise make it `textFieldOriginalWidth`

like this:

```
.frame(width: isEditing ? 0 : textFieldOriginalWidth, height: textBoxHeight)
```

Of course this doesn't disable it. But it will not highlight and allow the user to past, copy, etc...

It will have the desired outcome.

## Update

To get the OTP to "Autofill" or show up in the keyboard.

Set the `Textfield`'s  `.textContentType` as `.oneTimeCode`.
The OS should handle the rest read the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view).

Which you have done for textfield.

This action should paste your copied text:

```
Button(action: paste, label: {
    Text("Paste")
})

.
.
.
func paste() {
    let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
    guard let pastedString = pasteboard.string else {
        return
    }
    viewModel.otpField = pastedString
}
```

Comment: Hi again @Alhomaidhi, this was the original code if you remember, unfortunately, I had to change it because the paste functionality won't work if I add this frame setup. I need to be able to use the clipboard to to paste numbers in textfield. Doing this .frame(width: isEditing ? 0 : textFieldOriginalWidth, height: textBoxHeight) I believe moves the "Paste" box out of the view.

Comment: Hello, I know this isn't the best solution but, the keyboard should have the past functionality + maybe add a button that mimics the action?

Comment: I see. can you help me with that? I'm still tryong to find a guide for that in SwiftUI

Comment: Hi @Alhomaidhi, I updated my question. The .oneTimeCode works perfectly, however, it is also a requirement to be able to paste different text on the textField. Hope you can help me again. Thanks.

Comment: is there a way can show/hide the button when long tap/double tap on TextField? This way you can show only the button when you double tap on text field or long tap.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to make the frame of TextField's width equal to 0 when editing but doing this will disable paste functionality so @Alhomaidhi's solution is to add a paste button.

I did this and made it appear when TextField is double or long tap to mimic the iOS clipboard.

Here is the complete code:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class OTPViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var numberOfFields: Int
    
    init(numberOfFields: Int = 6) {
        self.numberOfFields = numberOfFields
    }
    
    @Published var otpField = "" {
        didSet {
            showPasteButton = false
            guard otpField.last?.isNumber ?? true else {
                otpField = oldValue
                return
            }
            if otpField.count == numberOfFields {
                hideKeyboard()
                showPasteButton = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Published var isEditing = false {
        didSet {
            if !isEditing { showPasteButton = isEditing }
        }
    }
    
    @Published var showPasteButton = false
    
    func otp(digit: Int) -> String {
        guard otpField.count >= digit else {
            return ""
        }
        return String(Array(otpField)[digit - 1])
    }
    
    private func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct CXLRPOTPView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = OTPViewModel()
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    private let textBoxWidth: CGFloat = 41
    private let textBoxHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 8
    private let spaceBetweenLines: CGFloat = 16
    private let paddingOfBox: CGFloat = 1
    private var textFieldOriginalWidth: CGFloat {
        (textBoxWidth + CGFloat(18)) * CGFloat(viewModel.numberOfFields)
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                // DOUBLE TAP AND LONG PRESS LISTENER
                Text("123456")
                    .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                        viewModel.showPasteButton = true
                    }
                    .frame(width: textFieldOriginalWidth, height: textBoxHeight)
                    .background(Color.clear)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 90, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
                    .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5) {
                        self.viewModel.showPasteButton = true
                    }
                
                // OTP TEXT
                HStack (spacing: spaceBetweenLines) {
                    ForEach(1 ... viewModel.numberOfFields, id: \.self) { digit in
                        otpText(
                            text: viewModel.otp(digit: digit),
                            isEditing: viewModel.isEditing,
                            beforeCursor: digit - 1 < viewModel.otpField.count,
                            afterCursor: viewModel.otpField.count < digit - 1
                        )
                    }
                } //: HSTACK
                
                // TEXTFIELD FOR EDITING
                TextField("", text: $viewModel.otpField) { isEditing in
                    viewModel.isEditing = isEditing
                }
                .font(Font.system(size: 90, design: .default))
                .offset(x: 12, y: 10)
                .frame(width: viewModel.isEditing ? 0 : textFieldOriginalWidth, height: textBoxHeight) // SOLUTION THAT PREVENTED TEXT HIGHLIGHT
                .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .background(Color.clear)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .accentColor(.clear)
                
                // PASTE BUTTON
                Button(action: pasteText, label: {
                    Text("Paste")
                })
                .padding(.top, 9)
                .padding(.bottom, 9)
                .padding(.trailing, 16)
                .padding(.leading, 16)
                .font(Font.system(size: 14, design: .default))
                .accentColor(Color(.white))
                .background(Color(colorScheme == .light ? UIColor.black : UIColor.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(7.0)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7).stroke(Color(.black), lineWidth: 2)
                )
                .opacity(viewModel.showPasteButton ? 1 : 0)
                .offset(x: viewModel.numberOfFields >= 6 ? -150 : -100, y: -40)
            } //: ZSTACK
        } //: VSTACK
    }
    
    func pasteText() {
        let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
        guard let pastedString = pasteboard.string else {
            return
        }
        let otpField = pastedString.prefix(viewModel.numberOfFields)
        viewModel.otpField = String(otpField)
    }
    
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    private func otpText(
        text: String,
        isEditing: Bool,
        beforeCursor: Bool,
        afterCursor: Bool
    ) -> some View {
        return Text(text)
            .font(Font.custom("GTWalsheim-Regular", size: 34))
            .frame(width: textBoxWidth, height: textBoxHeight)
            .background(VStack{
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 65)
                ZStack {
                    Capsule()
                        .frame(width: textBoxWidth, height: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "#BCBEC0"))
                    
                    Capsule()
                        .frame(width: textBoxWidth, height: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "#367878"))
                        .offset(x: (beforeCursor ? textBoxWidth : 0) + (afterCursor ? -textBoxWidth : 0))
                        .animation(.easeInOut, value: [beforeCursor, afterCursor])
                        .opacity(isEditing ? 1 : 0)
                } //: ZSTACK
                .clipped()
            })
            .padding(paddingOfBox)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0.0, *)
struct CXLRPOTPView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CXLRPOTPView(viewModel: OTPViewModel())
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```