# TextSelection copy nothing

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
Text("Hello, world!")
            .textSelection(.enabled)
            .padding()
```

Whan i press the "Hello, world!" and select the copy, it nerver copy any thing

Comment: are you running on an actual device or in the simulator?

Comment: works well for me, on macos 12, catalyst, ios15 devices and simulator. What system are you using?

Comment: This looks to be a bug. I get the issue, with the error in the console: `[Pasteboard] ... "Cannot load representation of type com.apple.uikit.attributedstring"`. Tested on real device on iOS 15 (full release) and Xcode 13 RC

Comment: I was running it on both of simulator and device
I use Xcode13 RC, MacOS 12 beta7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an iOS bug. I got the same issue on an iOS 15.2.1 device but not on iOS 16 simulator. A workaround:

```
Text($someText)
.contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
  Button("Copy", action: {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = someText
  })
}))
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66903216