# Make the TextField Multiline - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

I start learning SwiftUI and I'm trying to make the TextField multiline but it didn't work, also when I click on the return button it dismisses the keyboard.

```
TextField("Description", text: $categoryTitle)
.lineLimit(nil)
```

so how I can fix it?

Comment: UITextField is one line only - Use UITextView for multiline

Comment: UITextView is pretty easy to make into a View. The main problem is that you can't use Color or Font.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471973/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-textfield-in-swiftui for code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Since iOS 16

The `lineLimit` modifier works as expected if you choose `.vertical` value for the `axis` parameter. And it also supports `range` now:

```
TextField("Title", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
    .lineLimit(5...10)
```

[image: Demo]

---

#### Since iOS 14

Form iOS 14 and with Xcode 12, it's available as `TextEditor`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = "Multiline \ntext \nis called \nTextEditor"

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
    }
}
```

---

#### iOS 13

Also, if you want to support iOS 13, you can take at **[look this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60039382/5623035)** to port `UITextField` inside SwiftUI with full access to all of its properties.

Comment: Yea, finally Apple added it 

Comment: @Mojtaba Hosseini This seems to break keyboard avoidance? Or is it just me?

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 16.0+** supprts multiline TextField.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var description: String = """
                Join us, and let's force unwrap SwiftUl's
                birthday presents. Note that although
                this activity is optional, we may have
                guards at the entry.
                """

    var body: some View {
        Form {
           TextField("Description", text: $description, axis: .vertical)
              .lineLimit(5) // You can restrict min & max visible lines 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Finally 