# What is the equivalent of textarea in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

What is the equivalent of textarea in SwiftUI? Where I could have multiple lines of text input. And specify size of this area? 
HTML example is here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea
I have searched a lot without any luck.

I have tried to use TextField in SwiftUI, but if user writes long text, the text goes out of the screen.

```
TextField("notes")
.background(Color.yellow)
.lineLimit(3)
```

Comment: Look at this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471973/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-textfield-in-swiftui

Comment: Thanks. Is it the only option for now? There is still no simpler solution in SwiftUI?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The equivalent of TextArea in SwiftUI is TextEditor. Apple introduced it in mid 2020

```
var body: some View {
    TextEditor(text: $profileText)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
}
```

Here is a reference that describes it in more detail: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-multi-line-editable-text-with-texteditor