# Pass standard type (Int, String, etc.) to view hierarchy using SwiftUI's Environment

Tags: swift, swiftui

I know we can pass custom `ObservableObject`s types using the `.environmentObject(_:)` and then access it from subviews using `@EnvironmentObject` special properties.

But what it we want to pass non-custom, standard `Int`, `String` properties around views?

The only candidate I can see is:

`func environment<V>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, V>, _ value: V) -> some View`

But it seems that it only works for fixed, non-custom, `KeyPath`s such as `\.colorScheme`.

In other words I am looking to pass around a `@State` using the Environment.

Comment: A `@State` should be bound to the `View` it belongs to. Why do you need to pass an `@State`? Wrap the `Int` or `String` in an `ObservableObject` and pass that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

`@State` is designed to be used in a single view (or passed via `Binding` to a descendant view). It is just a convenience to avoid making an `ObservableObject` class for every view. But if you are passing data to multiple views that are not tightly connected, you should wrap your data in an `ObservableObject` class and pass around with `.environmentObject()`

#### Explanation

To elaborate on krjw's comment, and *why* you can't pass around `@State` properties, let's talk about what the `@State`, `@ObservedObject`, `@EnvironmentObject`, `@Published`, and `@Binding` property wrappers are actually doing.

Because your view is a struct, it is a value type. When your app's state changes, and views must be shown differently as a result, your current view struct is thrown away, and a new one created in its place. But this means that data cannot be stored inside the struct, because it would get thrown away and replaced by an initial value every time the view changes.

Enter the `ObservableObject` protocol. When you create an object that conforms to this protocol, and mark one of its properties `@Published`, this is just nice syntactic sugar to say, "I've got this reference object, which I intend to represent state; please set up some Combine publishers that broadcast any time there's a change." Because it's a reference type, it can sit somewhere in memory, *outside* of our views, and as long as our views have a reference to it and subscribe to its publisher, they can know when it changes, and refresh accordingly.

But remember, we said that our views are structs. Even if you assigned one of their properties a reference to the `ObservableObject` and subscribed to its publishers, we would lose that information whenever the struct was recreated. This is where the `@ObservedObject` wrapper comes in. In effect, all that's doing is saying, "Store the reference and subscription to this object *outside* my struct, and when my view is recreated, make sure I know I'm supposed to reference and listen to this object."

The `@EnvironmentObject` does the same thing, it is just nice syntactic sugar to avoid having to pass in an `ObservedObject` via initializer. Instead, it says, "Trust me, one of your ancestors will have an object of this type. Just go ask them for it."

So really, that would be enough to do everything we need to do in SwiftUI. But what if I just need to store and watch a `Bool` for changes, and only need it in a single view? It's a bit heavy handed to make a whole class type just for that. That's where the `@State` property wrapper comes in. It is basically just combining the functions of the `ObservedObject`/`@Published` stuff with the `@ObservedObject` stuff. It says, "Keep this data *outside* my struct's memory (so it isn't thrown away on refresh), and notify me when anything changes." That's why you can modify your `@State` properties, even though modifying a struct's properties should recreate the struct; the data is not *really* inside your struct.

`@State` is just a condensed, convenient way to get the functionality of an `ObservableObject` class with a `@ObservedObject` wrapper, that will only be used in one struct.

For completeness, let's talk about `@Binding`. Sometimes, a direct descendent of our view may need to modify the `@State` variable of its ancestor (e.g., a `TextField` needs to modify the `String` value held by its parent view). The `@Binding` property wrapper just means, "You don't need to store this data (because its already stored by another view/object); you just need to look at it for changes and be able to write changes back."

NOTE: Yes, under the hood, `@State` is not literally setting up a class conforming to `ObservableObject` and another `@ObservedObject` wrapper; its much more efficient than that. But *functionally*, from a usage perspective, that's what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

When it is needed, I pass @State via arguments or constructor as Binding. You can find wide usage of this approach in my code for post [How do I create a multiline TextField in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471973/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-textfield-in-swiftui/58639072#58639072)

Comment: The idea to use the Environment is to avoid passing objects along subviews deep in the hierarchy where they will be actually needed.