# SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable - UITextView detect change with attributed text

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I am unable to have the textview detect changes in a `@Binding` property because it has attributed text and not text. How am I to detect these changes and update accordingly. I have tried making the UITextView itself a state, but that isn't working. Here is my code:

```swift
struct MultilineTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: NSMutableAttributedString
    @State private var view = UITextView()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        self.view.isScrollEnabled = true
        self.view.isEditable = true
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.autocorrectionType = .no
        self.view.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()
        return self.view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        print("Update")
        let all = NSMakeRange(0, text.length)
        text.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 20.0)!, range: all)
//        text.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white as! Any, range: all)
//        text.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.black as! Any, range: all)

        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "hi^", options: [])
        let matches = (regex.matches(in: text.string, options: [], range: all))

        for match in matches {
            print(match.range)

            text.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: match.range(at: 1))
        }

        uiView.attributedText = text
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471973/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-textfield-in-swiftui/58639072#58639072) which might be helpful for how to work with `UITextView` via representable in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Coordinator class inside your UIViewRepresentable.
you don't need prop @State private var view = UITextView().
you create uikit view, that you want swiftui to display in makeUIView method.
than update any binding prop you want(in uitextview it probably text or attibutedtext)
you create coordinator and conform uitextviewdelegate protocol and attach it to your view in makeUIView (view.delegate = context.coordinator) and you are able to access textViewDidChange delegate method to manage binding value:

```
struct MultilineTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
@Binding var text: NSAttributedString

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
    let view = UITextView()
    view.isScrollEnabled = true
    view.isEditable = true
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.autocorrectionType = .no
    view.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()
    view.delegate = context.coordinator
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    uiView.attributedText = text
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    var parent: MultilineTextView

    init(_ parent: MultilineTextView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        parent.text = textView.attributedText
    }
}
```

}

ps sorry for my eng