# Receiving updates from UIKIT to use in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui

So basically I have created `UIKit` TextFields, I want to be able to take advantage of delegate functions from `UIKit` and their return values, and use them to toggle let's say a @State variable in `SwiftUI`. How would I be able to achieve this? A little more in-depth, I want to be able to use the `isFirstResponder` dot method in `UIKit` and return a specific textfield, then do something with that data to toggle its corresponding element 'on', that I made in `SwiftUI`.

Comment: The approach in [How do I create a multiline TextField in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58639072/12299030) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To represent `UIKit` views and view controllers in `SwiftUI`, you create types that conform to the `UIViewRepresentable` and `UIViewControllerRepresentable` protocols. Your custom types create and configure the `UIKit` types that they represent, while `SwiftUI` manages their life cycle and updates them when needed.

[Interfacing with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit)