UITextView clips text when placed in ScrollView
I am using UIViewRepresentable to use UITextView in SwiftUI.
In a regular VStack, everything is showed in full and correct (Screenshot upper paragraph), however, there is a strange behaviour when placing the TextView in a ScrollView. If a lot of text is present, it just removes it (Screenshot lower paragraph). I have placed dividers in the screenshot to show that the layout size of the UITextView is indeed correct, but the UITextView just chooses to not show everything and sort of clips it.
It only shows the entire text when I explicitly provide a frame. However this means that I need to make a Binding object from the TextView to my Main view and this make the scrollview jittery in a LazyVStack.
SwiftUI View:
var body: some View
{
    VStack
    {
        TextView(text: text)
        
        Rectangle().frame(height: 1).foregroundStyle(.red)
        
        ScrollView
        {
            TextView(text: text)
            
            Rectangle().frame(height: 1).foregroundStyle(.red)
        }
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)
}

TextView:
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
let text: String

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView
{
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.text = text
    
    textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textView.isSelectable = true
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    
    textView.backgroundColor = .clear
    textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    textView.textContainerInset = .zero
    
    return textView
}

func updateUIView(_ textView: UITextView, context: Context) { }

}


Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77062851/content-of-uiviewrepresentable-in-a-scrollview-is-not-rendered-properly?rq=2

textView.text = text needs moved to updateUIView
