# TextView doesn't synchronize the binding variable in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I created a simple `TextView` like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var inputText: String

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UITextView {
        return UITextView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
//        uiView.text = self.inputText
        self.inputText = uiView.text
    }
}
```

And the main view contains a variable with a `@State` wrapper.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    @State private var inputText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $inputText)
            TextView(inputText: $inputText)
        }
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test()
    }
}
```

As I understand, the `TextView` and `TextEditor` are connected by this `inputText`, who has a `@Binding` wrapper in the definition of `TextView`. Thus if I type in one of them, another should show the same text. However, to my surprise, the text in these two are completely separated with each other.

If I change the `self.inputText = uiView.text` to `uiView.text = self.inputText`, then when I type in `TextEditor`, the `TextView` would show the same text, but if I type in `TextView`, then nothing happens in `TextEditor`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840437/swiftui-uiviewrepresentable-uitextview-binding

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for mentioning this! Turns out a `Coordinator` is exactly what I need.