# How can I make a text editor with some style in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

How can I make a text editor with some style in SwiftUI?  It seems that there a text editor can not be as customizable as the text field.

How could I achieve a result like this (here the users text is white)?

My issue is how can I set the text color to white and set the background color in a text editor.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear // First, remove the UITextView's backgroundColor.
    }
    @State private var input = ""
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            TextEditor(text: $input)
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(.white) // Text color
                .background(Color.blue) // TextEditor's Background Color
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How could you add a clip shape or corner radius to the text editor?

Comment: Just use `.cornerRadius()` or `.clipShape()` modifier depending on your requirement.

Comment: How could I add a text placeholder?

Comment: @Nighthawk for a placeholder, you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63106247/14073532).

Answer (score 2):

From iOS 16 you can use

```
TextEditor(text: $notes)
    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

Comment: I hope more people see your response! This is it.