# AttributedString in UITextView is trimmed at the top

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am using attributed string in UITextView. Sample playground can be found [here](https://github.com/ShivamPokhriyal/BuggyUITextView/tree/master/TextViewAttributedString.playground)

This is a quick summary of what is happening.

UITextView has padding issue which can be solved using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42333832/6671572) thanks to @Fattie

**I set attributed string in UITextView.**

*then I calculate textView's height using [sizeThatFits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622625-sizethatfits) method which I am guessing is giving me correct height.*

**But when I run it, text is trimmed at top, and some space is left at the bottom.** Please run the sample playground from [here](https://github.com/ShivamPokhriyal/BuggyUITextView/tree/master/TextViewAttributedString.playground)

I guess this might be the reason why textView comes with a default padding but I am not completely sure of it.

Strange thing is, **I tried the same with UILabel and it seems to be working perfectly fine with the same settings.** You can try the same in the above playground after uncommenting the UILabel.

Can anyone tell me why is this issue happening with UITextView?

Answer (score 0):

Solved after using

```
let htmlText = text.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
let mutableText = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: htmlText,
        options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
        documentAttributes: nil)
```