# Stack overflow caused by custom UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextView subclass that has the following code:

```
@IBDesignable class UITextViewFixed: UITextView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        textContainerInset = .zero
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        var b = bounds
        let h = sizeThatFits(CGSize(
            width: bounds.size.width,
            height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        ).height
        b.size.height = h
        bounds = b
        contentInset = .zero
    }
}
```

It was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42333832/362840) stack overflow answer for producing UITextViews without any text padding. Unfortunately when I call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` on adjusting the container view that holds my text view, a recursive loop occurs. It calls `layoutSubviews()` and then calls `setup()` which then calls `layoutSubviews()` etc. This carries on until it causes a stack overflow. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by removing this bit:

```
var b = bounds
let h = sizeThatFits(CGSize(
    width: bounds.size.width,
    height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
).height
b.size.height = h
bounds = b
contentInset = .zero
```

Comment: you can use a boolean to check if that operation has been done before...